# Login Failed Redirect to different page

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I am working on my website, and I incorporated the login form in the homepage, not a separate page. It works great unless you have an error "enter wrong info" Then the displayed errors mess up the form margins and formatting. So I would like to have it redirect to a separate page (login.php) if the user entered the wrong details. My question is how to do that and also is it possible to keep the displayed erros? Thanks in advanced, Josh

Here is my code for handling errors:

```
/**
    * login - The user has submitted his username and password
    * through the login form, this function checks the authenticity
    * of that information in the database and creates the session.
    * Effectively logging in the user if all goes well.
    */
   function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember){
      global $database, $form;  //The database and form object
  /* Username error checking */
  $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
  if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0){
     $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
  }
  else{
     /* Check if username is not alphanumeric */
     if(!preg_match("/^([0-9a-z])*$/i", $subuser)){
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
     }
  }

  /* Password error checking */
  $field = "pass";  //Use field name for password
  if(!$subpass){
     $form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
  }

  /* Return if form errors exist */
  if($form->num_errors > 0){
     return false;
  }



  /* Checks that username is in database and password is correct */
  $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
  $result = $database->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));

  /* Check error codes */
  if($result == 1){
     $field = "user";
     $form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
  }
  else if($result == 2){
     $field = "pass";
     $form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
  }

  /* Return if form errors exist */
  if($form->num_errors > 0){
     return false;
  }

  /* Username and password correct, register session variables */
  $this->userinfo  = $database->getUserInfo($subuser);
  $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
  $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
  $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];

  /* Insert userid into database and update active users table */
  $database->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid);
  $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
  $database->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

  /**
   * This is the cool part: the user has requested that we remember that
   * he's logged in, so we set two cookies. One to hold his username,
   * and one to hold his random value userid. It expires by the time
   * specified in constants.php. Now, next time he comes to our site, we will
   * log him in automatically, but only if he didn't log out before he left.
   */
  if($subremember){
     setcookie("cookname", $this->username, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
     setcookie("cookid",   $this->userid,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
  }

  /* Login completed successfully */
  return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect with the header function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: You'll need to pass the errors in the URL if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make an array for error like:
$error = array();

if($result == 1){
     $field = "user";
     $form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
     $error[] = "Username not found";
  }
  else if($result == 2){
     $field = "pass";
     $form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
    $error[] = "Invalid password";
  }

  /* Return if form errors exist */
  if($form->num_errors > 0){
     return false;
  }


And in the last count error array like:

if(count($error) > 0){
echo implode("<br />",$error);
}


if there is no error then like:

if(count($error)==0){
header("location:redirectpage.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a redirect function a few more times on your website, I suggest you create a class or a function for this:

this works if you work with a menu variable in the url: (working example)

```
    class myHeader {

    function redirect($menu) {
    $this->host= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $this->uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\'); 
    $extract="http://$this->host$this->uri/?menu=$menu";
    $this->head($extract);
    }

    function head($extract) { header("Location: $extract"); exit; }

    }
    $header = new myHeader();
```

to display an error to a user and you want to give it a special look you can work with sessions:

```
 if($result == 1) {
 $_SESSION['fail_user'] = 1;
 }

 if($result == 2) {
 $_SESSION['fail_password'] = 1;
 }
```

then on your login.php:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['fail_user'] == 1) {
?>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Please enter a valid Username</p>
<?php 
}
?>
```